# WPF EF how to add linked entities to rdlc without using view or stored procedures

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework-5, rdlc

I'm learning RDLC reporting in VS2010. I have created a WPF Application and an entity framework model in my project.

I'm able to add dataset of single entity, a view or stored procedures which will explicitly join the related entities to it. There's no problem in doing all this.

But I wonder if I can create rdlc reports using the EF entity objects including all it's linked entities through navigation property. So that I can use all the fields of it's parent or detail entity, etc

When I add entity object as dataset, I get all those navigation property but can not use their fields in the report.

Do RDLC support such thing ?? Please guide...